# iOS - Unexpected behaviour from custom component

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have written a custom slide up menu component, which uses UIKitDynamics to slide the panel up and down from the view.  It works fine on one controller because I initialise it in `viewDidLoad`, however on my new screen I need to initialise the screen in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as when the panel slides onto the screen it needs to be placed directly above a specific view.  This seems to cause problem when the `hideMenu` function is called from the delegate.

If I move the initialisation code for my custom component to `viewDidLoad` I can see the panel sliding up and down as I'd expect, but it appears under my tableView (I can see it because the view is slightly translucent).  I tried to fix this by calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` to revalidate the view hierachy, but it didn't change anything.

The code below describe how I initialise my component. I don't believe its necessary to post the inner workings of BasePanel as its simply initialisation code for the view and a method to slide the panel up and down

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    basePanel = BasePanel(sourceView: self.view!, items: [""], aboveView: self.tableView)
    basePanel?.delegate = self
}
```

Why am I experiencing this behaviour? Is there a reason why initialising a view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` could change runtime behaviour?

**ANSWER** Moving the code to `viewDidAppear` caused the window to behave correctly. I want to leave this question open for someone to answer with a WHY does this happen?

I understand how the view lifecycle works but why would this cause some functions in my custom component to not bind correctly?

Working code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    basePanel = BasePanel(sourceView: self.view!, items: [""], aboveView: self.tableView)
    basePanel?.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Perhaps try `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.YOURVIEW)`

Comment: Tried moving code to `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` using the code above but it didn't make any difference - the view still renders behind tableView

Comment: How about in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Yeah, viewDidAppear works, see my update :)